# Grafana Singlestat panel with Delta calculation for Prometheus divison

Tags: data-visualization, grafana, prometheus

I have a question about visualization of prometheues metrics in grafana.

When I have a PromQL-Statement like the following:

```
(sum(metric1 - metric2)
 OR on() vector(1)
)
/
(sum(metric1)
  OR on() vector(1)
)
```

I will get the right calculation in grafana for the configuration option *Value Stat* "**Current**". But when i want the calculation for "**Delta**" the result is not comprehensible.

Could someone please explain this to me?
How could I get the right delta result for a PromQL-Statement with a division when selecting "Today so far" in grafana?